# Why are no results detected in my searchbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

can someone help me to detect the issue of my searchbox. I made a searchbox in javascript that proofs the input with a defined keyword list. If a word is matching, then the "HARMI-SOIL 8.0/15 Result Box" should show up, if it does not match the Result Box should stay hidden (display:none).

My Issue is that after typing in a matching word and klicking enter, the Result Box does not show up. Javascript tells me the word are not matching, even though they should. Just when I click on the cross (x) and deleting the input the Result Box shows up and Javascript tells me the words are matching. I am grateful about any hint. Thank you very much!

```js
var wordsHarmi = [
    "Bodenhilfsstoff",
    "Dünger","Duenger",
    "Harmi",
    "Soil",
    "Harmi-Soil",
    "Boden",
    "Mineralien",
    "Wurzelwachstum",
    "Nährstoffe", "Naehrstoffe",
]

let harmiSuche = document.getElementById('harmi-suche')
const inputSearch = document.getElementById('input-suche');

inputSearch.addEventListener('search', (event) => {
    const searchString = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(event);

    
    // Iterate over words array to find the input value
    for (let index = 0; index < wordsHarmi.length; index++) {

        console.log("works");
        
        const wordFound =     wordsHarmi[index].toLowerCase() ==searchString;

        if(wordFound){
            console.log("Word found");
            harmiSuche.style.display = 'flex';
        }
        
        else {
        harmiSuche.style.display = 'none';
        console.log("Word not found");
        }
    }
})
```

```css
 #harmi-suche{
        display: none;
    }
    .col-1 {width: 100%;}
    .device-margin-left{
        margin-left: 5.625%;
    }
    .device-margin-right{
        margin-right: 5.625%;
    }
    .column{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }


    .sans-serif-caption{
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.75em;
        line-height: 1.375em;
        font-weight: normal;
        color:#444342;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .search{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 40%;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #444342;
        opacity: 1;
        align-items: center;
        padding:1%;
    }
    .mobile-search{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #444342;
        opacity: 1;
        /*align-items: center;*/
        align-content:space-between ;
        padding:1%;
       /* margin-left:7%;*/
        margin-right: 7%;
    }
    .mobile-search input{
        border: none;
        background-color: #F5EAAB;
        width: 100%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .page-search{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #444342;
        opacity: 1;
        align-items: center;
        padding:1%;
    }
    .page-search input{
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
    }
    .page-search input:focus{
        border: none;
    }
    .suchergebnis{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        /*justify-content: center;*/
    }


    .kachel3{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: left;
        padding:1%;
        border: 4px solid #BF9D1D ;
        border-radius: 3%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        /*margin-left: 1%;*/
        background-color: #FFFEF9;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #00000026;
        height: auto; 
    }
    .standardbutton-anordnung{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
    .standardbutton{
        width:auto;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #444342;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #FFFEF9;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 1%;
    }
    .standardbutton:hover{
        color: #BF9D1D;
        border: 1px solid #BF9D1D;
    }
    .standardbutton:focus{
        color: #BF9D1D;
        border: 1px solid #BF9D1D;
    }
```

```html
<div id="sucheingabe" class=" suchergebnis col-1">
    <li class="col-3"></li>
    
        <div class="page-search sans-serif-text-mobil">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Was suchst du?" id="input-suche">
            <image src="media/search-24px.svg" alt="search-icon" />
        </div>
    
    <li class="col-3"></li>
</div>

<div id="suchfilter" class="column">


        <div id="harmi-suche" class="item kachel3 device-margin-right device-margin-left">
            <div class="column" style="width: 100%;">
                <h3 class="serif-heading-3">HARMI-SOIL 8.0/15</h3>
                <p class="sans-serif-caption">HARMI-Soil 8.0/15 ist ein mineralischer Bodenhilfsstoff auf Basis von Gesteinsmehl und natürlichen Zusätzen, die zu 90% aus Produktionsresten bestehen und  deshalb nicht extra hergestellt werden müssen.</p>
                <div class="standardbutton-anordnung col-1" style="justify-content: flex-end; margin-top: 2%;">
                    <button class="standardbutton sans-serif-caption"><a href="./harmi-soil.html">Mehr erfahren</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `inputSearch = document.getElementById('input-suche');` there is no input in your html

Comment: @butalin already updated it, just forgot to paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed your code, have a look.

#### A line of missing HTML and some Javascript. I have not touched the CSS.

1. First of all, you need to transform your original array elements into lowercase, just like you did with the **inputSearch** variable.
2. Your for loop is in the wrong place and unnecessary. For example, your array **wordsHarmi** has 11 elements, hence the loop will run 11 times. It is memory intensive and also complicated. I recommend using Javascript's include function.
3. The html file was missing an input field which was causing the error.

```html
<!-- I put the search input box in the following position in index.html file-->
    <input id="input-suche" type="search"/>
    <div id="suchfilter" class="column">
        <div id="harmi-suche" class="item kachel3 device-margin-right device-margin-left">
```

4. Your JavaScript file had to be rewritten. Here's the solution. I've tested it and it works.

```
//I have changed your variable delaration to 'const' instead of 'vars', but you can still use var if you want to.
const wordsHarmi = [
    "Bodenhilfsstoff",
    "Dünger","Duenger",
    "Harmi",
    "Soil",
    "Harmi-Soil",
    "Boden",
    "Mineralien",
    "Wurzelwachstum",
    "Nährstoffe", 
    "Naehrstoffe",
];

const harmiSuche = document.getElementById('harmi-suche')
const inputSearch = document.getElementById('input-suche');

/*Before running the actual code, you have to transform your array elements into lowercase, 
just like you transformed the searchinput into lowercase*/

//This is a modern Javascript map function,
//we stored the new array from your original array with all elements in lowercase
let wordsHarmi_lower = wordsHarmi.map(function(v){
    return v.toLowerCase();
})
//uncomment to see what it does if you are curious. 
// console.log(wordsHarmi_lower);


inputSearch.addEventListener('search', (event) => {
    const searchString = event.target.value.toLowerCase(); //saves lowercase of the search string

    // Javascript's includes function returns true or false by iterating into array.
    //For loop isn't the best solution for this code
    const found = wordsHarmi_lower.includes(searchString);

    // any word you enter will now be changed into lowercase, and compared to the wordsHarmi_lower array,
    // return true or false based on whether the element is found. You can uncomment the code below to see that.
    // console.log(found);
    

    //Therefore, the logic
    if(found === true){
        harmiSuche.innerHTML = "Hurray we found your user"; 

    } else {
        //you can insert a whole div and anything else you like here
        harmiSuche.innerHTML = "Sorry not found";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change condition

```
if(wordFound == true){
        console.log("Word found");
        harmiSuche.style.display = 'flex';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Lovely. It is a useful hint, but I just forgot to paste the input field (now updated). I already had it with type="search" before. Do you have by chance another idea?

Comment: Hi, I updated answer for your updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Once a match is found, you need to stop the iteration (otherwise it will only work for the last item in the list :) )

```
       if(wordFound){
            console.log("Word found");
            harmiSuche.style.display = 'flex';
            break; // <--- this is the key line!
        } else {
         ......
       }
}
```